# How to fix Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier and Invalid left-hand side in assignment errors when use jquery.i18n.propeties plugin

Tags: jquery, translation, typeerror, uncaught-exception

I am using `jQuery.i18n.properties` plugin to translate language on my website.
My setup used to work but all of a sudden the plugin has stopped working and the following errors show up in the console:

> - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> - Invalid left-hand side in assignment errors

I downloaded 2 jquery.i18n files and pasted to webappp->resources->bundle (the bundle is a folder created by me) and then I declared two  tags to use this plugin :

```
<!-- jquery i18n for multi language --> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="${contextPath}/resources/common/js/jquery.i18n.properties-1.0.9.js" charset="utf-8"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="${contextPath}/resources/common/js/jquery.i18n.properties-min-1.0.9.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<!-- end config multi language -->
```

I also created two properties files for English and Korea which is the languages in which I will translate to in my page with file names is ItemLabel_. After ''_'' is prefix with ''en'' for English or ''kr'' for Korean. And after that. Below is my using in code :

```
$.i18n.properties({
  name:'ItemLabel', path :CONTEXT_PATH+'/resources/bundle/', 
  mode :'both', 
  language: 'en',
  callback:function(){}
})
```

---

Because these errors seem to be tied to the plugin's code, I could not fix it and as a consequence the translation is not working anymore on my website.

Could someone guide me on how to fix my issue?

Comment: Something must have changed in your logic to cause the errors. If you double click the errors in the console they should take you to the line of your code which causes the issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is build - in plugin of jquery , I can only use , not edit code. what should I do ?

Comment: The error may be raised from the plugin, but it will be how your code is calling it that's the problem. That's what you need to diagnose.

Comment: I followed by steps as guidline and it is very good before. I have not also changed any code line but today maybe there is something wrong. I am very confused in solving this

Comment: Unfortunately we can't help you without seeing your code that creates the problem

Comment: Oh. Sorry for this negligence. I will send to you immediately

Comment: I downloaded 2 jquery.i18n files and pasted to webappp->resources->bundle (the bundle is a folder created  by me) and then I declared two <script> tags to use this plugin :

<!-- jquery i18n for multi language -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="${contextPath}/resources/common/js/jquery.i18n.properties-1.0.9.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${contextPath}/resources/common/js/jquery.i18n.properties-min-1.0.9.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- end config multi language -->

Comment: - I also created two properties files for English and Korea which is the languages in which I will translate to in my page with file names is ItemLabel_.
After ''_'' is prefix with ''en'' for English or ''kr'' for Korean.
And after that. Below is my using in code :
 $.i18n.properties({
    name:'ItemLabel',
    path : CONTEXT_PATH+'/resources/bundle/',
    mode :'both',
    language: 'en',
    callback:function(){}a

Comment: Please use the `edit` button under the question to add more information to it

Comment: Hi Mr Rory. I editted my question in clearly format to read easily. Please help me. Thank you